VSCode shows a warning in a task definition when I use "linux": "command"
I am running VSCode on an Ubuntu 22.04 host that is up to date with patches.
I am creating custom tasks. VSCode shows these warnings for each of the tasks in the PROBLEMS window.
Missing property "command", [Ln X, Col Y]
Note that all the tasks run fine. So, it is not stopping me from moving forward. In each of those tasks I use:
"type": "process",
"args":[
          <bunch of args>
            ],
"linux": {
                "command": "<command>",
            },

rather than just "command". When I just use "command", not inside the "linux", the warning goes away.
"type": "process",
"args":[
          <bunch of args>
            ],
"command": "<command>",

I guess I am confused why when I use "command" inside "linux" VScode thinks there is no command defined. Especially since it runs the command just fine.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Chris

why not just add a dummy platform-agnostic command?
